# Pin one specific program to the rightside of the taskbar

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

I run multiple instances of the same program, which is taking up too much space on my taskbar.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like (or something similar)

[image]

**Q:** How can I get a specific program and all of its instances to open on the right side of my taskbar?

Comment: Why not just enable combined icons?

Comment: That's what I've been using as a temporary solution. Just fill up the whole taskbar, let each instance of the program run and then combine the icons and when it's finished decombine. But this is not the permanent solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Have found an improved temporary solution by using [3rd-party software](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). I now have the option to choose which programs I want to combine and which I don't want to combine. Still, its a temporary solution. Hoping for a permanent fix.